# Android back button act like hardware back button

Tags: java, android, button, back

I have an `Activitiy` with a `ListView` and some items. When I click on one item I get to the next `Activity`.

On the new `Activity` when I click the hardware back button I get back to the `Activity` with the `ListView` and all the data is still there.

Using the back button (as defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`) in the upper left corner all the data is gone.

How can I make this software back button act like the hardware back button?

Comment: What do define in the `manifest`? And what is `software button`? You mean button in the `ActionBar`?

Comment: Yes the software button is the one in the ActionBar. Simply got "android:parentActivityName="activities.MainActivity" in the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onBackPressed()` method in the `activity` that doesnt have the `listview`
and in there you check if you want to act like the super (go to previous activity doing nothing) or do something (clear the data), and then call the super

Comment: I don't think this behaviour is the one he expects, is the contrary. For what I understood, the back button is working fine, the problem is when clicking the back btn of the action bar

Comment: Exactly, when i click the one in the action bar the data in the previous activity is gone

Comment: If you are talking about the app icon button in the actionbar you simply have to write finish () in its onclicklistener.

Comment: @user3878500 make sure if that helped you that you mark it as accepted answer :) it will give the one who created this answer more reputation points. you also can up vote it using the arrows on the left side of the answer :)